# Should I Create a new .net 4.5.1 WFC Client Proxy with every call

Tags: wcf

I have created an application that will be doing .net to .net communications. From what I understand using TCP is the optimized way of doing this.

I created a proxy by using the "Add Service". reference in Dev studio, and opened it as follows..

```
 NetTcpBinding tcp = new NetTcpBinding();
 string endPoint = string.Format("net.tcp://{0}:{1}/{2}", m_configuration.IpAddress,
          m_configuration.Port, ServicesEndpointId);
 m_proxy = new ProxyClient(tcp, new EndpointAddress(endPoint));
```

At the moment, I am creating a single instance of this proxy, and just reusing for each call to it. I have an exception handler, and handle a EndpointNotFoundException for when the other server end may not be up and running (which is likely)

This all worked fine when I was initially using http (not tcp), but now, if the server is down, or even after some idle time, I seem to be getting the following exception...

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException
```

I found some other posts that mention using a channel factory etc etc, and also a post that mentions to use

```
proxyInstance.InnerChannel.Faulted += new EventHandler(ProxyFaulted);
```

However I don't have a InnerChannel on my proxy, and the other channel stuff seemed a lot low level (more like remoting use to be - I like the total abstraction away from all this using WCF)

So, my question is, should I just be creating a new instance of the proxy for each call? Will the old proxy clean itself up (there does not seem to be any close etc on it)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions here!

Answer (score 0):

It would be safe to use new client for every call and dispose it as soon as the operation finishes to minimize memory footprint. `ClientBase<TChannel>` implements IDisposable so I would use using block (therefore client will be disposed when execution leaves the block). If you would not dispose the proxies .net will some day dispose it. But you risk that in heavy load your proxies (unused and not disposed yet) will hit limit of connections that can be opened with the server and you could end up with exception that maximum number of opened connections have been reached.

There are some guidelines to using using block with WCF clients [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx).

IMHO using one proxy for every call is not safe because the `ClientBase<TChannel>` is not thread safe (I presume your proxy could be called by multiple threads/users at the same time). If you still went this way, you would have to lock access to the proxy and therefore serializing access to it. This would result in performance drop or maybe even in timeouts. So I would definitely not use it this way.

Comment: Thank you for that feedback pepo. Doing some more reading, there are a few more "gottyas" then I thought using WCF. For example according to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/10/27/performance-improvement-of-wcf-client-proxy-creation-and-best-practices.aspx), I should not be creating my end point in code (as it disables caching). Also I should be calling Open manually. I did want avoid using the channel factory way of consuming the services, as really did not want to use to use a shared assembly (for the contracts)